# Доступ к содержимому векторов в режиме отладки

Tags: отладка, вектор, gcc, c++

Использую g++ версии 4.8.1, среду разработки NetBeans 7.2. В программе объявляю вектор `A_vec` чисел типа double. Заполняю вектор элементами. Ставлю точку останова в программе после заполнения вектора и запускаю в режиме отладки. На вкладке "Анализ выражений" выражение `"A_vec.size()"` выдает 10, то есть элементы в векторе есть. Однако при попытке вычислить `"A_vec[0]"` выводится непонятное `"A_vec[0] = @0x1942218"`, а если вычислить `"(double)A_vec[0]"`, и вовсе возникает окно с ошибкой `"Cannot access memory at address 0x1942218"`. В чем может быть дело? В векторе точно есть элементы, почему отладчик их не видит?

**Обновление**

Ошибка возникает даже в минимальных демках. Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<double> a(3,1);
    cout << a.at(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Обновление**

Проблема наблюдается только при отладке в Windows (использую отладчик gdb, входящий в состав пакета MinGW). На ОС семейства Linux все ОК.

Comment: Хорошо. А просто массив показывает?

    int main () {
       double a[] = {1, 2, 3};

       cout << a[1] << '\n';
    }

Только в одну строку не мешайте (надеюсь, код в Вашем примере на самом деле не в одну строку записан?).

Comment: Просто массив показывает без проблем.
Не в одну строку, я просто не знаю, как сделать форматирование в комментариях. Буду признателен, если подскажете.

Comment: Форматирование кода в комментариях

    перед каждой строкой кода ставим 4 пробела
      а первую и последнюю строки кода
    отделяем пустыми строками

продолжаем комментарий.

Странно у Вас. Попробуйте просто оттранслировать свой пример

    g++ t.c -g

и запустить отладчик (все из командной  строки)

    gdb ./a.out

Работает?

Comment: @avp, результат тот же самый. Прилагаю скрин, чтобы вы сами могли посмотреть: http://hsto.org/files/dd5/2ca/367/dd52ca3675e04cb68ad48b8a3be52114.png

Comment: Винда... 

(как-то, наверное, настраивается, но лучше переходите на Linux).

Comment: @avp: Ну или на Visual Studio — там проблем такого порядка обычно не наблюдается, у них неплохой отладчик.

Comment: Проверил на Linux. Действительно, там проблема с доступом к значениям элементов вектора не возникает. Возможно, проблема в самом MinGW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычный `gdb` (проверял в Linux) прекрасно все видит:

```
(gdb) p a[0]
$1 = (double &) @0x6040d0: 0
(gdb) p a[8]
$2 = (double &) @0x604110: 8
(gdb) p a.size()
$3 = 10
(gdb) p a
$4 = {<std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >> = {
      _M_impl = {<std::allocator<double>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x6040d0, 
      _M_finish = 0x604120, _M_end_of_storage = 0x604150}}, <No data fields>}
```

Может сами значения где-то на экране среды разработки теряются?

**Обновление**

Попробовал. Естественно, все работает

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gdb ./a.out 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3.1) 7.7
  ....
(gdb) br 18
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048925: file c.cpp, line 18.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/avp/hashcode/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at c.cpp:18
18      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
(gdb) p (double)a[0]
$1 = 0
(gdb)
```

а с чего бы ему не работать?

(я работаю просто из командной строки без всяких IDE).

**Обновление 2**

А почему тогда размер показывает?

Более того. Он же пишет:

```
 Мне удалось получить доступ к элементу с помощью вот такого выражения: "(double)a._M_impl._M_start".
```

значит данные есть.

Я просто никогда не использовал `NetBeans`, поэтому понятия не имею, что и где там смотреть (включился, просто чтобы кто-то подхватил и, может быть, помог автору).

Comment: На экране только адрес почему-то отображался. Можете попробовать вывести "(double) a[0]"? Или моя ошибка в том, что нужно приводить к типу double&?

Comment: Насколько я понял, нет простого способа обратиться к элементу. print a[0] выдает "(double &) @0xc3748a00: <error reading variable>".
Мне удалось получить доступ к элементу с помощью вот такого выражения: "*(double*)a._M_impl._M_start".

Comment: Попробовал. Естественно, все работает

    avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ gdb ./a.out 
    GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3.1) 7.7
      ....
    (gdb) br 18
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048925: file c.cpp, line 18.
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: /home/avp/hashcode/a.out 
    
    Breakpoint 1, main () at c.cpp:18
    18      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    (gdb) p (double)a[0]
    $1 = 0
    (gdb) 

а с чего бы ему не работать?

(я работаю просто из командной строки без всяких IDE).

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что у @DarkGenius включена оптимизация и компилятор просто выбросил сам массив. Поэтому, очень сложно показать содержимое.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Я проверил не только из-под NetBeans, но и из-под Dev-C++. Результат тот же. Размер он показывает только в том случае, если в коде программы есть вызов функции size(). В противном случае, как я понимаю, функция вырезается компилятором из кода и поэтому недоступна (gdb выдает: "Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined").

Comment: Получить доступ по `(double)a._M_impl._M_start`, видимо, удалось только по той причине, что это просто обращение к полям, и там были правдоподобные значения. А вот есть ли по данному адресу реальные данные - вот это вопрос.

Нужно искать, где в настройках нетбинса прописываются настройки компилятора,  выбросить `-O2` и заменить его на `-O0 -ggdb`. Либо просто собрать отладочную версию.

Comment: Собрал отладочную версию в Dev-C++. print a[0] по-прежнему выдает "(double &) @0xc3748a00: <error reading variable>". Выходит, нельзя просто так обращаться к элементам через оператор [].

Comment: А данное поведение наблюдается во всех программах (даже в минимальных демках)? Или только в Вашей? Покажите окрестности кода.